# OpenLayers 2 MultiPolygon holes

Tags: openlayers-2

I have trawled over many pages about the OpenLayers handlerOptions for drawing polygon holes. I can't create a polygon hole in existing polygons using the following:

```
var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature (
    farmpaddocks,
    OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,
    {
      handlerOptions: {holeModifier: "altKey", multi: true, drawingHole:true,},
      title: "Draw Feature",
      displayClass: "olControlDrawFeaturePolygon",
      featureAdded: setAttributes
    }
);
```

All I get are tiny dots on the vertices... no polygons lines are drawn when pressing "alt" key.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a little example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_DR_/xj5AH/). Code example:

```
var options = {
    div: "map",
    zoom: 12,
    center: [-9074392.9993436, 5021122.97485],
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector()
    ]
};
var map = new OpenLayers.Map(options);
var draw = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(
    map.layers[1],
    OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon,
    {
        autoActivate: true,
        handlerOptions: {
            holeModifier: "altKey"
        }
    }
);
map.addControl(draw);
```

Comment: Thanks for that , Its just drawing another polygon for me on top of the existing. I forgot to mention it was a wfs layer from postgis that I am trying to digitize the hole on. The code you sent works for me as a vector layer but not on a wfs layer. Should it be the same approach for a multipolygon wfs layer?

Comment: @Hadlew: I can correctly use the provided code. Did you press the alt key while making the hole? And you should be able to use this code for a wfs layer. You will just have to listen to the DrawFeature control. Or do you wish to Modify existing polygons and add holes in them?

Comment: I understand now what is happening. I was trying to edit and existing polygon. I can now digitize "new" polygons with holes but not pre existing ones...hope that make sense. I would need to run ST_Difference in postgres for those. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @Haydlew:If you wish to add holes to existing Polygons, I'll suggest that either edit this question, or open a new Question. I am not sure if that (adding holes to existing polygons) is possible, so I won't keep your hopes up.

Comment: Thanks Devdata, I will open up a new question if I have issues (adding holes to existing polygons) I plan on passing the selected polygon geom and the digitized polygon geom to the postgis function ST_Difference(geom, geom).I will see how it goes I guess.  Thanks again

Comment: It works well with polygons, but doesn't work with multipolygons (multi:true). How can I draw hole in real MultiPolygon (not in many Polygons)?